# Building native OpenCV using Android NDK gives "undefined reference to 'cv::String::deallocate()'"

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I'm attempting to use OpenCV with the NDK in Android Studio. As you may notice I'm using another native library called GStreamer.

My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

def getNdkCommandLine(ndkRoot, target) {
    def gstRoot
    def opencvRoot
    gstRoot = 'C:/local/gstreamer-1.0-android-arm-1.8.0'
    opencvRoot = 'C:/local/OpenCV-3.1.0-android-sdk/OpenCV-android-sdk'

    if (ndkRoot == null)
        throw new GradleException('NDK not configured')

    return ["$ndkRoot/ndk-build.cmd",
            'NDK_PROJECT_PATH=build',
            'APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=src/main/jni/Android.mk',
            'NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application.mk',
            'GSTREAMER_JAVA_SRC_DIR=src/main/java',
            "GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID=$gstRoot",
            "OPENCV_ROOT_ANDROID=$opencvRoot",
            "$target"]
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            // Avoid using the built in JNI generation plugin
            jni.srcDirs = []
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['build/libs']
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mytestcom.mytestapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    // Before compiling our app, prepare NDK code
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
    }

    // Need to call clean on NDK ourselves too
    clean.dependsOn 'ndkClean'

    // Build native code using mk files like on Eclipse
    task ndkBuild(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
        commandLine getNdkCommandLine(android.ndkDirectory, 'TARGET_ARCH_ABI=armeabi-v7a')
    }

    task ndkClean(type: Exec, description: 'Clean JNI code built via NDK') {
        commandLine getNdkCommandLine(android.ndkDirectory, 'clean')
    }

    //Renames APK to current versionName found in Android Manifest
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def outputFile = output.outputFile
            if (outputFile != null && outputFile.name.endsWith('.apk')) {
                def fileName = "My_Test_App-${versionName}.apk"
                output.outputFile = new File(outputFile.parent, fileName)
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile project(':openCVLibrary310')
}
```

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := gstplayer
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := player.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(OPENCV_ROOT_ANDROID)/sdk/native/jni/include

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := gstreamer_android
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -landroid
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi)
GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ARM)
else ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)
GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ARMV7)
else ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),arm64-v8a)
GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ARM64)
else ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86)
GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_X86)
else ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86_64)
GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_X86_64)
else
$(error Target arch ABI not supported)
endif

ifndef GSTREAMER_ROOT
ifndef GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID
$(error GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID is not defined!)
endif
GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID)
endif

GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH  := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT)/share/gst-android/ndk-build/

include $(GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH)/plugins.mk
GSTREAMER_PLUGINS         := $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CORE) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_PLAYBACK) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CODECS) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_NET) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_SYS) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CODECS_RESTRICTED) $(GSTREAMER_CODECS_GPL) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_ENCODING) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_VIS) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_EFFECTS) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_NET_RESTRICTED)
GSTREAMER_EXTRA_DEPS      := gstreamer-player-1.0 gstreamer-video-1.0 glib-2.0

OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_CAMERAMODULES:=off
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC

include $(GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH)/gstreamer-1.0.mk
include $(OPENCV_ROOT_ANDROID)/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
```

Application.mk:

```
APP_PLATFORM=android-19
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
```

I'm using OpenCV-3.1.0-android-sdk, NDK r10e, Android Studio 2.1, Windows. I've tried using a different version of OpenCV (2.4.11) but it didn't help.

```
C:\local\OpenCV-3.1.0-android-sdk\OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\include\opencv2\core\cvstd.hpp
Error:(625) undefined reference to 'cv::String::allocate(unsigned int)'
Error:(667) undefined reference to 'cv::String::deallocate()'
Error:(667) undefined reference to 'cv::String::deallocate()'
Error:(667) undefined reference to 'cv::String::deallocate()'
Error:(667) undefined reference to 'cv::String::deallocate()'

C:\local\OpenCV-3.1.0-android-sdk\OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp
Error:(443) undefined reference to 'cv::error(int, cv::String const&, char const*, char const*, int)'
Error:(459) undefined reference to 'cv::error(int, cv::String const&, char const*, char const*, int)'
Error:(682) undefined reference to 'cv::Mat::deallocate()'
Error:(571) undefined reference to 'cv::fastFree(void*)'
Error:(592) undefined reference to 'cv::Mat::copySize(cv::Mat const&)'
```

Comment: I believe the issue is that the .hpp files being used require the external libraries to be built and linked to. For example, **libopencv_core.a**. So following [this](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/prebuilts.html) link I've added a section to my Android.mk file that should add a module as a `PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY`. I've fixed all the errors that resulted from this addition but I'm back to the same error as before (undefined reference to...)

Comment: That's for certain. I don't see any setting for libraries that your application links with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation for these errors is that the OpenCV code being used in GStreamer doesn't have access to the rest of the library, so it's failing to find basic methods like `allocate()` and `deallocate()`.

The solution was to include some prebuilt static libraries in the Android.mk so that these references are defined. So after `include $(OPENCV_ROOT_ANDROID)/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk` I added these lines to add the relevant libraries:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := opencv-tbb
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := opencvLib/3rdparty/libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libtbb.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := opencv-core
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := opencvLib/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libopencv_core.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/opencvLib/include/
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := opencv-tbb
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := opencv-imgproc
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := opencvLib/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libopencv_imgproc.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/opencvLib/include/
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := opencv-core
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

The `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES`variable sets the include files that correspond to that library. In this case the include folder works for both libraries.

Now for the GStreamer code to be able to use these libraries we have to add `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := opencv-core opencv-imgproc` to the gstplayer module which references the 2 added OpenCV modules.

Edit:

Also I forgot to mention I changed `APP_STL := gnustl_static` to `APP_STL := gnustl_shared` in Application.mk

Comment: In the OpenCV.mk, there are two functions: `add_opencv_module` and `add_opencv_3rdparty_component`. They generate `LOCAL_MODULE`s in the fashion opencv_*. e.g opencv_core, opencv_imgproce ... I was curious why you did not get module name confliction error, then I realized that you used '-' instead of '_'. So if you try to use `opencv_*` you might end up with removing all 3 modules you defined :D.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue a few days ago. Imo, you should try to replace `LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -landroid` with `LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -landroid`.